# Animating sphere squash and stretch

Tags: animation, mesh

I am trying to animate a sphere for a small project I am making that involves the sphere "talking". I know it sounds weird, but I need help on this. My problem is that I am trying to animate the spheres to scale down on the zed axis, but also move downwards to the floor at the exact same time. I could just move the sphere downwards while scaling it, but that is time-consuming. Is there an easy method for scaling the sphere while moving it downwards at the same time? Here are some pictures.
What I want to be able to animate quickly:[image]
Normal resting position[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered a way to fix this: moving the origin point of the sphere to the bottom. Now it moves up and down on the origin point.